# Nodejs function asynchrone

Tags: node.js, async.js

This function return a promise but I want return a list of string

````
  let response_Transporters = await axios.get('____');
  var data_Transporters = response_Transporters.data.rows;
  var N_Transporters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data_Transporters.length; i++){
    N_Transporters[i] = data_Transporters[i].value;
  }
  return N_Transporters;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

An async function always returns a promise, this is by design.

See this link for more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value

When you call this method make sure you put `await` before the call.